# How to Send Email with Attachment in workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-365-developer

In SharePoint online, how to send email with an attachment through a workflow without using any third party tool?

Comment: What's the question here? Can you please specify the problem you are facing and what solution you need.

Comment: Hi Asad ,Send Email With Attachment via workflow

Comment: You mean how to send an email with an attachment via a workflow? That's your question right?

Comment: Your Organisation has presumably spent quite a lot of funding on SharePoint to store your content in it.  You're now asking to take that content and make a copy of it (presumably stored in Exchange) and send it as an email attachment.  Store the content in SharePoint and send a link out via Workflow.  Bring your users to the content.  Don't send the content to your users.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Online, If you are using SharePoint Designer for workflow then it is not possible to Send Email with attachments. It is not possible OOTB.

You can share Document link in mail.So,User can easily open that link from mail and access document.

It is limitation by design in SharePoint.

Comment: Any custom solution possible?